# Which brand of furnace is more reliable and lasts longer?

Tags: furnace

I'm in the market for a gas furnace and was wondering which brand is more reliable and lasts longer. Sort of like which car brands are known to last longer and/or be more reliable.

Most of the brands out there do not seem to be really famous (top furnace brands discussed here: http://gas-furnaces-review.toptenreviews.com/). Of the list in the link, I personally only have heard of Carrier, Coleman, and Trane.

Comment: Brand recommendations, like product recommendations, are not really suitable for Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Tester101 I think this question will not "tend to become obsolete quickly" (per Tester101's criterion) like other product or service recommendations. This is asking the exact opposite...which furnace brands last longer.

Comment: @CarlGammaSagan we decided long ago that [shopping type questions would be off topic](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/a/608/33).  The text in the banner is simply  an automatic response that's displayed when a question is closed for this reason.

Comment: @Tester101 Ok, but that automatically generated banner text does seem misleading because it suggests that there's only one reason why shopping type questions are off topic.

Comment: @CarlGammaSagan you'll have to take that up with the site designers.  You can always ask questions about the site on the [meta](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com) site.